# Awk Scripting printf ignoring my sort command

Tags: awk

I am trying to run a script that I have set up but when I go to sort the contents and display the text the content is printed but the sort command is ignored and the information is just printed. I tried this code format using awk and the sort function is ignored but I am not sure why.

Command I tried:

```
sort -t, -k4 -k3 | awk -F, '{printf "%-18s %-27s %-15s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4 }' c_list.txt
```

The output I am getting is:

```
Jim Girv    199 pathway rd    Orlando      FL  
Megan Rios  205 highwind dr   Sacremento   CA  
Tyler Scott 303 cross st      Saint James  NY  
Tim Harding 1150 Washton ave  Pasadena     CA
```

The output I need is:

```
Tim Harding 1150 Washton ave  Pasadena     CA   
Megan Rios  205 highwind dr   Sacremento   CA  
Jim Girv    199 pathway rd    Orlando      FL  
Tyler Scott 303 cross st      Saint James  NY
```

It just ignores the sort command but still prints the info I need in the format from the file.
I need it to sort based off the fourth field first the state and the third field next the town then display the information.

An example where each field is separated by a comma.

```
 Field 1   Field 2          Field 3   Field 4
Jim Girv, 199 pathway rd,   Orlando,  FL
```

Comment: can you please explain what have you tried?

Comment: it should be in question. add it in your question by editing and remove the comment. Thanks.

Comment: One line of data is inherently sorted.  Please show 4-10 lines of data in the input, and what you're getting as output, and what you think you should be getting.  There's no indication of how the data is being fed to `sort`; it takes file names or reads standard input.  Similarly, `awk` can read standard input or files.  If you specify files on the `awk` command, it will ignore the sorted standard input. Note that leading blanks in the fields after the comma could make a difference; you'd need to specify `-k4,4b` to ignore those.  You should probably be using `-k4,4 -k3,3` anyway.

Comment: sort -t, -k4, -k3 | awk -F, '{printf "%-18s %-27s %-15s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4 } '

Comment: yes i tried to in general use the sort command  sort -t, -k4,4 -k3,3 it sorts the file in perfect order but when I try to use the pipe operator and awk printf it does the second command and does not sort the first command.

Comment: Edit your question to show clear, simple sample input and expected output. Also show the actual output of just running your sort command on the sample input

Comment: to simplify your problem, please include your input file (sample data if needed) into your command line, i.e.` sort -k4 -k3 file | awk ... NOFILE! (right?)` What you describe makes me think you are doing `(...) sort ... | awk ... file` Good luck.

Comment: shelter i added the full command line in my question I am so sorry if the question is confusing. I have been working on the program all I need is the sort command to work but I am not getting a syntax error, from what I can figure it is a logic error but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're doing `sort | awk 'script' file` instead of `sort file | awk 'script'` so `sort` is sorting nothing and consequently producing no output while `awk` is operating on your original file and so producing output from that. You should have noticed that your `sort` command is hanging too for lack of input and you should have mentioned that in your question.

To demonstrate:

```
$ cat file
c
b
a

$ sort | awk '1' file
c
b
a

$ sort file | awk '1'
a
b
c
```